# What do the git statistics mean?

Tags: git, git-diff, diffstat

I probably don't know how to search for this, but can't find what the git stats that are shown when you do a git pull or a "git show --stat 947a403" (--stat is not in the manpage)
It's supposed to be line ins/del but they don't really match.

```
 TODO                           |    6 +++-
 htdocs/main/js/ek.balcony.js   |   18 +++++++---
 htdocs/main/js/ek.face.js      |    3 +-
 htdocs/main/js/ek.main.js      |    2 +-
 htdocs/main/js/ek.tsakiseis.js |    2 +-
 octave/.point2tsak.m.kate-swp  |  Bin 66 -> 0 bytes
 octave/initialiseEdf-balc.m    |   68 ------------------------------------
 octave/initialiseEdfbalc.m     |   75 ----------------------------------------
 8 files changed, 22 insertions(+), 152 deletions(-)
```

What are these numbers and the + and - ? Is this something like a levenshtein distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the manual is here: http://invisible-island.net/diffstat/ or diffstat(1)
The counts are as reported by diff. The difference between +/- and the count is just rounding.

Answer (score 2):

These show the files changed and the lines added and removed in each.  In your example, 3 files changed, and in ek.face.js, one line was added, one line was removed.

Comment: I updated the example. What about face ane main.js both with the same +/- but different numbers?

Comment: In cases where you have a whole lot of changes, it doesn't wrap the line, rather it scales the lines shorter.  Thus in your case TODO has 6 changes, but shortening them to fit in 4 characters, 3/4 of them are adds, 1/4 of them are deletes.

Answer (score 1):

```
TODO ... 3 additions 1 deletion
htdocs/main/js/ek.balcony.js ... 7 additions 3 deletions
htdocs/main/js/ek.face.js ... 1 addition 1 deletion
```

As for the number... I'm not 100% sure.  It may be a line-count as to how many lines were added/deleted.

Comment: Actually... my answer was correct in that it is the quantity of "additions/deletions".  It is not indicative of how many "lines" were changed... but rather how many "diff" sections needed to be applied.

Comment: Hmm it doesn't seem to be a version.

Comment: It might be a line-count... i.e. how many lines changed... but I never bothered to look too closely.